# Why does the sorting algorithm work correctly?

Tags: algorithm, performance, sorting, big-o

I got a sorting algorithm. I know it could have been written in many other and more simple ways but that's not the point of my question.

Here is **the algorithm**:

```
sort(A : Array of N, i : N, j : N)
assert j-i+1 isTwoPotency
if A[i] > A[j] then swap A[i] and A[j]
if i+1 < j then
    k:= (j − i + 1)/4
    sort(A, i, j − 2k)
    sort(A, j − 2k + 1, j)
    sort(A, i + k, j − k)
    sort(A, i, j − 2k)
    sort(A, j − 2k + 1, j)
    sort(A, i + k, j − k)
```

My question is, **why does the algorithm work correctly** in the following case?

```
sort(A, 1, length(A))
```

and the array would be:

```
A[1 . . . length(A)]
```

**length(A) is a two potency** and we can **assume** that there are **no identical numbers inside the array**. I already tested it, got no errors so I assume it works correctly. But how can I prove that the algorithm always works correctly in these conditions?

And I am wondering how long does the algorithm needs as running time.
It would be great if you could give me the running time as big theta notation (that's the one I understand the best)

f(n) = Θ(g(n))

Comment: If you don't know, if your code works correctly, then write tests, which will check that.

Comment: I already tested it, I just want the prove as mentioned an the running time. (I edited the question)

Comment: You must have had some idea what the statements you were writing were doing when you wrote the algorithm. How did you intend it to work?

Comment: I tested  out the code with 16 numbers, its sorted all the number from index 2 forward, but the first number was unsorted.. so it almost worked, but not really, at least not with the numbers I tested. my test numbers:(11,21,13,41,15,16,71,28,19,10,1,12,3,14,5,6). your algorithm sorted it to:(11,1,3,4,6,10,12,13,14,15,16,19,21,28,41,71).. notice the first number did not get sorted.

Comment: due to the recursion used in the algorithm it's a bit hard to keep the entire overview for me. But I intended that the array gets sorted in more smaller parts, as the indices show...

Comment: @SergioFernandez the pseudocode uses 1-indexed arrays.

Comment: my array started from 1 not zero.  I still got the results I posted.

Comment: @Snelfie so this isn't an algorithm you wrote? Where did you get it from?

Comment: @SergioFernandez I tested on your input, but it worked ok. Here's my code: https://gist.github.com/paulhankin/a00eb9948834269f3111fa2e0f435a08

Comment: it's an algorithm of an old exercise sheet. I just modified it a bit and wanted to see if it still works correctly. I'm very interested in the structure how the algorithm goes through the array. That would explain me why it works like it does. I've got a drawing link a tree structure in mind.

Comment: @PaulHankin so I assume that the first number in the array was sorted correctly too?

Comment: @PaulHankin, unless I wrote the code down wrong. look at my code below, I'm running it, and the first element is 11. so, nope.

Comment: Weird -- I can't see any difference between your code and mine (except for the language), but my version works correctly in this case.

Comment: no there is a difference in your code and mine, your array starts from 0. not 1, when I modified by array to start from 0, and changed the line, swap(a[i],a[j]) to sawp(a[i-1],a[j-1]) it works, so, I'll loop though teh code to see why it makes a difference, but thats what you did different from teh pesudo code. your array stared from 0.

Comment: @SergioFernandez perhaps your function should be `sort(var a: array[1..16] of integer; ...)` ? I've forgotten how pascal works, but perhaps this causes your 1-based array to be treated as 0-based?

Comment: @PaulHankin, dude I just copied his code line by line, look at my pascal code, look at the code he wrote. its the same code. you where the one who modified your code, and therefor fix the bug, I guess without knowing.

Comment: @SergioFernandez I looked at your pascal code and found a bug -- you're accidentally 0-indexing `a` inside `sort`. Here's code that simply prints out `a` from index 1 to 16 inside `sort` -- you can see it starts 21 and not 11. https://ideone.com/VzE02z

Comment: @PaulHankin yup your right, I just copied the code blindly. I should have set a type arr = array[1..16] of array; then use as a parameter in sort(var a:arr;...) and the var a:arr = (11,...,6)... anyway, I removed what I posted, just for the fact, that it did not address his question, of the run time. But again, that is how it was written in the question just array of n no range specified at that point... I just copied the code provided. you keep on saying I made a mistake, look at the code, I just used the code provided, thats all. its no my code.but I should have caught that.

Comment: but again, its not very productive just to say it does not work, I should have just fixed the code and answered to big O question. but again, no error in "MY code", my code is just the above code line, by line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Correctness

Divide the array into four quarters, A1 through A4, and consider the sub-array each element should end up in.

- After the first two recursive calls, all elements that belong in A1 are located in A1 or A3.  Similarly all A4 elements are located in A2 or A4.
- After the third recursive call, all A1 elements are in A1 or A2, and all A4 elements are in A3 or A4.
- After the next two recursive calls, all A1 elements are in A1 in sorted order, and all A4 elements are in A4 in sorted order.  This leaves all A2 and A3 elements in either A2 or A3.
- After the last recursive call all A2 and A3 elements are in the correct sub-array in sorted order.  Thus the array is sorted.

Illustration:

[image: Schematic illustration of the above explanation]

#### Runtime

Notice that when we execute the algorithm on an array of length `n`, we have to execute the algorithm six times on arrays of length `n/2`.  This yields the following recurrence:

- `T(1) = O(1)`.
- `T(n) = 6 T(n/2) + O(1)`.

Solving the recurrence we get `T(n) = O(6^log2(n)) = O(n^log2(6)) ≈ O(n^2.585)`